# How do you group by the most common string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For each unique string in column 1 what is the most common string in column 2?

For example for the table:

```
1 | 2
-----
A   a
A   a
A   a
A   b
B   b
B   b
B   b
B   a
B   c
C   c
C   d
C   a
```

The results should look like:

```
X | Most common | Weighting
A        a         0.75
B        b         0.60
C        a         0.33
```

I wanted to use the GROUP BY clause, but I don't know any aggregate functions that work for strings. Also, I know there is already some ambiguity as to what to do in the case of ties (like for C). In my application though I only care about cases where the weighting is >0.50, so the ambiguity doesn't matter.

I am using SSMS 2014.

Answer (score 1):

The CTE below computes the weighting for each record in your table as a quotient of counts.  Then, we can retain the first record from each `col1` partition using row number.  Note that I don't handle the case of ties, though we could easily enough add another ordering break the tie.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT col1, col2,
        1.0 * COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2) /
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) weighting
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT col1, col2, weighting
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY weighting DESC) rn
    FROM cte
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY col1;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

All these answers seem so complicated:

```
select col1, col2, col2_cnt * 1.0 / col1_cnt
from (select col1, col2,
             count(*) as col2_cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over (partition by col1) as col1_cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by col1, col2
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly straightforward with `count`; here's a quick option:

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT nm1
        ,nm2
        ,count(*) AS ct
    FROM #a
    GROUP BY nm1
        ,nm2
    )
    ,CTE2
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY nm1 ORDER BY ct DESC
            ) rn
        ,ct * 1.0 / (sum(ct) OVER (PARTITION BY nm1)) AS wt
    FROM CTE
    )
SELECT nm1
    ,nm2
    ,wt
FROM CTE2
WHERE rn = 1
```

Note that `row_number` can be unpredictable if you have ties - if you want it to return both values when there are ties, use `rank` instead.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with `count` and `row_number` window functions.

```
select top 1 with ties col1,col2,weighting
from (select col1,col2,1.0*count(*) over(partition by col1,col2)/count(*) over(partition by col1) as weighting
      from t
     ) t
order by row_number() over(partition by col1 order by weighting desc,col2) --in case of ties the row with least col2 value will be picked up
```